# Is TEXT to VARCHAR(MAX) an implicit conversion?

Tags: sql-server, cast

I am copying TEXT columns to another table where the destination column is VARCHAR(MAX).

It appears that this is an implicit conversion and that I do not need to write an explicit CAST for it.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As detailed in the excellent [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), conversions from `text` to `varchar` can indeed be implicit.

[image]